# Can anyone explain me what does this particular print statement do in for loop?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
const int N = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
cout<<N<<endl;

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    cout << (i[a-i]%N)[a+i-1] << " ";
}
```

//It prints 1 2 3 4 5 i.e. the array what I didnt understand was
cout << (i[a-i]%N)[a+i-1] << " ";

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the CBCPAT, the Confusing But Correct Pointer Arithmetic Trick.

Since array subscription in C++ (and C) is done using pointer arithmetic, if `a` is an array and `i` is the index (an integer), then

```
a[i]
```

is equivalent to

```
*(a + i)
```

and since addition is commutative, this is the same as

```
*(i + a)
```

which in turn can be written as

```
i[a]
```

i. e. you're indexing the integer with the array (WTH?).

After having learnt this, you can easily rewrite the code to understand what it does: it is equivalent with

```
(a + i - 1)[(a - i)[i] % N]
```

which is just

```
(a + i - 1)[1 % N]
```

which is in turn

```
(a + i - 1)[1 % 5],
```

that is

```
*(a + i - 1 + 1)
```

which is

```
a[i]
```

Voilà. Screw the programmer who wrote this crap.

Comment: Note also, that it will work only if the first element of the table is equal to 1. `(a - i)[i]` written sanely is `a[i - i]` = `a[0]` = 1 (in this case). Anyway, I would sentence the programmer, who wrote this code to installing Windows 7 from floppy discs, at least ten times.

Comment: +1 solely for the last sentence. I'd +1 again for the great explanation if I could.